# Update startup.bat tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I'm working on tomcat7 project on Eclipse (only the manager part). I get the project [here](https://bitbucket.org/chittoor/tomcat7/overview). This is the first time I'm working on this kind of project, and when I turn on the server and look at my page, nothing has changed (It was only a test changing some string in *java/org/catalina/manager/LocalStrings_fr.properties*).

I guess the startup.bat is not updated or something like that. Nothing about it on Google (else the build of the project with Linux command line, but I'm working on Windows).

Does anyone knows what have to be done?

---

Edit: It seems that my question is not easyly understandable, so I put some pictures to explain:
I work on Tomcat7 in my workspace:

[image]

I try to change the [image] file (just to test, I need to work on servlets too).

When I change the language file as:

```
htmlManagerServlet.title=Gestionnaire d''applications WEB Tomcat TEST
```

instead of

```
htmlManagerServlet.title=Gestionnaire d''applications WEB Tomcat
```

I get nothing after re-run the server:

[image]

I hope it's more easy to understand.

---

Thanks

Comment: Do you know you [can get binaries](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi?Preferred=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.us.apache.org%2Fdist%2F) (i.e. ready to use)?

Comment: Thanks, but I think I can't modify directly the servlets with the binary files. Am I wrong?

Comment: After you change the source code (including the *.properties files) you need to rebuild Tomcat. Follow the steps [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/building.html).